# Linux write integer

Tags: c, linux

I want to read from file a number and increase the number than write it to file. I want to use read/write not fscanf/fprintf .I tried to change integer to string but i found on Google that the itoa doesn't exist in linux . This is my code :

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    int f;
    f=open(argv[1],O_RDWR);
    char c[10];
    read(f,c,10);
    int ceva=atoi(c);
    printf("%d ",ceva);
    ceva++;
    //itoa (ceva,c,10);
    lseek(f,0,SEEK_SET);
    write(f,ceva,sizeof(int));
}
```

Comment: You could do a sprintf() on the buffer you already have, and write that buffer to the file.

Comment: `sprintf(str, "%d", value)` converts an int to decimal base string.

Comment: Or may be write your own itoa function..That shouldn't be much difficult!

Comment: `write(f,ceva,sizeof(int));` --> `write(f,&ceva,sizeof ceva);`

Comment: wildplasser this is not a sollution, i've tryed this too :D

Comment: No, you have not tried this ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you have against `fprintf`?  You need to convert the integer to a string somehow.  Another option would be to use `snprintf` to convert the integer to a string then `write` the string.

Comment: i want to use this in a another project and there i should use pipe , and i think that i can't use fprintf  .

Comment: @user3052078: You *can* use `fprintf` on a pipe; just use `fdopen` to get a `FILE*` for the pipe's file descriptor.

Comment: @user3052078 You think you can't or you really can't ? There is a whole difference here.